# Всё ли так в этом предложении?

Tags: союзы, перечисление

Есть следующий случай:

> ...теперь и плебей, и патриций –
> заложники общей беды.

Всё ли так в этом предложении?
Интересует, можно ли говорить в данном контексте:

> теперь и плебей, и

Или лучше

> отныне плебей и

?

Правильна ли вторая часть по отношению к первой (которая "заложники общей беды")?

Уже всю голову себе изломал такими с виду простыми вопросами, потому что русский язык не родной. Заранее большое спасибо за ответ, буду вдвойне благодарен если укажете на правила, отвечающие за регуляцию подобных языков взаимодействий, хотелось бы изучить их на будущее.

Comment: *Теперь* — это о настоящем, а *отныне* — от сего дня и навсегда.

Comment: А в остальном предложение правильное?

Comment: "заложники общей беды"  - это устойчивое выражение, так говорят и в данном контексте оно употреблено правильно. И "Теперь" и "Отныне" будет верно. Просто "Отныне" больше делает акцент на моменте начала происходящего.

Comment: Первое "и" желательно убрать.

Answer (score -1):

Если вам русский язык не родной, но есть интерес к подобным вопросам, то могу вам посоветовать литературу связанную со славянской речью. Дело в том, что у нас много слов которые убрали, или запретили, или считают синонимами, и употребляют в одинаковых случаях, но прикол в том, что язык не так прост, и богатство его заключается в образности, коих много. Мы мыслим образами, а словами пытаемся описать образ возникший. Простите, если вы ждали краткий ответ.

Слова "отныне" и "теперь" похожи только по сути, да и то, по сути для тех, кто не задумывается о том, как бы точнее выразить (передать) свой образ. Остальное у славян.